# Create New Database By SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I have two database named: olddatabase and newdatabase. I want to create a new database named newdatabase2 then copy database structure from newdatabase to newdatabase2 and then convert data from olddatabase to newdatabase2.

To copy database structure from newdatabase to newdatabase2 I use `Transfer SQL Server Object` Task component in SSIS, and then execute SSIS Package to convert data. But in step 1 I dont now how to create new database named newdatabase2. Currently I create the database manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "Transfer Database Task". You can use it to make a copy of newdatabase to newdatabase2:

[image]

EDIT:

or you can use the "Copy Database Wizard" once. It will generate an SSIS package and a SQL Server job, then you can re-use it as many times as you want.

EDIT2:
it would't make much sense to open on BIDS because you will only see something like this:
[image]

I don't think these packages are meant to be editable.
You can access it, though:

[image]

Comment: This component copy database with data. I want copy datatbase structure only.

Comment: Thank you. I use "Copy Database Wizard" and create a SSIS package and a SQL job. But I dont find created SSIS package file location in my system.

Comment: check the job. It should have a step that calls the package. It is probably stored on Sql Server

Comment: Package Path is: "\NOVIN-DEVELOP\DTS Packages\Copy Database Wizard Packages\CDW_NOVIN-DEVELOP_NOVIN-DEVELOP_0". How I open this package in Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: Try the "Transfer SQL Server Object" task: http://awesomesql.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/copy-all-objects-from-one-database-to-another-in-ssis-using-transfer-sql-server-objects-task/